# Why the compiler does not throw error when something is on parenthesis?

Tags: c++

*Short history:* I was writing a MessageBox function, but for some reason I got interested in knowing what errors appear when removed his name, but not the arguments, the code would look like this:

```
//Before removing the name.
MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Test MessageBox"), TEXT("Test"), MB_OK);

//After removing the name.
(NULL, TEXT("Test MessageBox"), TEXT("Test"), MB_OK); // <- This don't thrown error...
```

When I click to compile I realize that does not leave any error, indeed, not IntelliSense throwed an error, I was quite surprised, the program itself ran perfectly, but obviously did not show any dialog or message box.

Based on what happened I would like to address the following questions:

- What actually happens when leaving the parameters in parentheses?. Why nothing happens?
- How might this affect in some pretty big program?, is a serious mistake to leave it?
- Does the program will weigh more? Or the compiler will take this into account?

Thanks in Advance...

PD: The application was compiled with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: That is one expression containing multiple *comma expressions*.

Comment: This looks like dupehammer abuse to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not so sure it's an abuse. It's the same question, just rephrased in a slightly different context. I can't see a significant difference between the two.